# Inserting many records while reloading the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form. I am inserting data to my database and sending those inserted details to mail.

After clicking the submit button I'm clearing all the variables but my problem is when I reload the page once again data inserting as a new record and anther mail is sending. I don't want to insert new record and send another mail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SupportPortal
{
    public partial class Support : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void clearallfields()
        {
            ProblemName.Value = "";
            ImpactDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            SeverityDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ProblemDescription.Value = "";
        }

        protected void Submitsupportform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string ticketNumber = string.Empty;
            string Problem = ProblemName.Value;
            string impact = ImpactDropDown.Value;
            string Priority = SeverityDropDown.Value;
            string problemdescription = ProblemDescription.Value;
            Byte[] bytImage = new byte[] { 1 };
            Byte[] bytImage1 = new byte[] { 1 };
            Byte[] bytImage2 = new byte[] { 1 };
            string FileName = "";

            try
            {  
                // Get the HttpFileCollection
                HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(hpf.FileName);
                    HttpPostedFile objHttpPostedFile = Request.Files[Request.Files.AllKeys[i]];
                    int intContentlength = objHttpPostedFile.ContentLength;

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        bytImage = new Byte[intContentlength];
                        objHttpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(bytImage, 0, intContentlength);
                    }

                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        bytImage = new Byte[intContentlength];
                        objHttpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(bytImage1, 0, intContentlength);
                    }

                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        bytImage = new Byte[intContentlength];
                        objHttpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(bytImage2, 0, intContentlength);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex; 
            }

            // inserting into database
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=ViveSupport;Integrated Security=SSPI");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateTicket", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", ProductName.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Version", ProductVersionDropDown.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Module", ModuleDropDown.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OperatingSystem", OSDropDown.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataSource", Datasource.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Browser", BrowserDropDown.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment1", bytImage);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment2", bytImage1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment3", bytImage2);

            con.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);

            String ticketNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ticketNumber"].ToString();
            con.Close();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { 
                                    new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)),
                                    new DataColumn("Module",typeof(string)),
                                    new DataColumn("Product version", typeof(string)),
                                    new DataColumn("OS",typeof(string)), 
                                    new DataColumn("Datasource", typeof(string)),
                                    new DataColumn("Browser",typeof(string))});
            dt.Rows.Add(ProductName, ModuleDropDown, ProductVersionDropDown, OSDropDown, Datasource, BrowserDropDown);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Table start
            sb.Append("<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 9pt;font-family:Arial'>");

            // Adding HeaderRow
            sb.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<th style='background-color: #f5f5f5;border: 1px solid #ccc;text-align: left;'>" + column.ColumnName + "</th>");
            }

            sb.Append("</tr>");

            // Adding DataRow
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");

                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td style='width:100px;border: 1px solid #ccc'>" + row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "</td>");
                }

                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }

            // Table end
            sb.Append("</table>");

            StringBuilder problemtable = new StringBuilder();
            problemtable.Append("<div><div><table style='font-size: 9pt;font-family:Arial'><tr><td>Problem: </td><td>" + Problem + "</td></tr><tr><td>Impact: </td><td>" + impact + "</td></tr><tr><td>Priority: </td><td>" + Priority + "</td></tr><tr><td>ProblemDescription: </td><td>" + problemdescription + "</td></tr></table></div></div>");

            StringBuilder footersignature = new StringBuilder();
            string to = ""; //To address    
            string from = ""; //From address    

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            string mailbody = sb.ToString() + problemtable.ToString();
            message.Subject = "Generated ticket Number is" + ticketNumber;
            message.Body = mailbody;
            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            for (var x = 0; x < Request.Files.AllKeys.Length; x++)
            {
                string file = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(upload_file1.PostedFile.FileName);
                // HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[Request.Files.AllKeys[x]];

                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                { 
                     try
                     {
                         message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Path.GetFileName(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))));  
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         throw ex;
                     }
                 }
              }

              SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); //Gmail smtp    
              System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");

              client.EnableSsl = true;
              client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
              client.Credentials = basicCredential1;

              try
              {
                  client.Send(message);
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {   
                  throw ex;
              }

              // method to clear all the fields
              clearallfields();
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Add a "Comitted" bool to the mix. Store it client side in a hidden Formular Field. Set it after the inserting into the DB was successfull. While this is not save for security purposes, it would be reliable enough for this case (accidental double posts).

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. Can you please explain a bit detail.

Answer (score 0):

Generally doing bulk changes or comits like this is not a good design. You want to have the user only Add, Edit or Delete one specific entry. And comit the moment the user is finished with that one. Gathering changes like this is not generally a good idea. It raises the danger of data loss and update race conditions exponentially. It barely works for IMAP, and IIRC that one is designed more like a proper, multi-insert Distributed Database.

If you want to still use this design, you have to memorize if one specific row has been comited already. You want to know wich row has "unsaved changes". A simple boolean value for each row would do this. With WebApplications persisting the data is a problem. In this specific case - as the data has very low security impact - you can have it send to the client and retreive it back from them as part of the Formular data.

Very important rule: No mater how much they *look* like a Desktop applications, Web Applications are still a 1980 HTML Webformular. All the old design decisions still apply. But luckily that old design did include a [hidden formular field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp). Something send to and send back from the user, that is not displayed. How to use such a field from ASP.Net is a bit outside my knowledge however.